# What does "unterminated quoted string meets end of file" mean in MacVim?

Tags: ruby, macos, macvim

I'm looking a way to compile Ruby code on OSX. I am using MacVim, and my code says:

```
puts "test"
```

I type `rubydo %`, and I get an error message `SyntaxError: eval:1: unterminated quoted string meets end of file`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `rubydo %`? And where are you typing it?

Answer (score 1):

Vim's `rubydo` command executes a *command*.  You may have thought it was a filename (and used "%" as the parameter, i.e., the current buffer). The `%` is ruby's alternate string delimiter, and depending on how `rubydo` is implemented, the bare "%" could be mistaken for the beginning of a string.

- [The % Notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) (Ruby Programming)
- [Vim documentation: if_ruby](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_ruby.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I fully understand that "rubydo" is a command.  My understanding was that it compiles/interprets the code.  If I'm mistaken, please let me know, because I would think it'd have no problem compiling such a simple program as described above.

As for the "%" field, maybe I don't know what it really does.  I tried typing ":rubydo" which, again, I thought was synonymous with saying "compile", but when I just typed ":rubydo" by itself, the error message says "argument required".  After some Googling I found something that said you need to put "%" after ":rubydo".

Comment: This is all a longwinded way of saying that I would LOVE some clear documentation explaining to me how I compile Ruby code on a Mac.  I've literally installed three programs already, and I can't find any explanation anywhere for an incredibly straightforward question.  I don't understand why coding documentation isn't clearer.